# React routing works but doesn't trigger app.route() functions in Flask

Tags: reactjs, flask, react-router

I currently have a project that is using React and Flask. I'm currently using routing which is fully operating and able to route to all to various web pages. However, when I navigate to the various pages through my web app, the respective app.route() declarations don't get called in Flask. They only get triggered if I directly request that link through my browser address bar. Also, the declared methods that use POST work fine. Is there any way the app.route() functions can get triggered via links within React if as it seems like it isn't requesting any information from the server side?

Comment: I think you're confusing client side routing and server side routing. If you're using react-router then you're specifically telling your browser NOT to request a resource from your server and instead treat the url as a global variable inside javascript

Comment: @azium thank you very much for the insight. That's what I thought at first but I believed React would load the requested page locally and also ping that page server side, triggering the specific app.route() on the server. I guess the only options now to get app.route() called is to either ping the url from the client when the page has been loaded locally or use server side routing. I think the second approach would be more aligned with the general approach. Do you think so? Thank you.

Comment: To be honest, I've never heard of anyone doing this. What would your app.route() calls even be doing?

Comment: I'm using them to for user session management.

Comment: and you specifically need to do that kind of management on page changes? there's almost certainly a better way of doing what you want

Comment: in any case.. react-router makes it super easy to do whatever you want on location change. you can check the auth example from the docs